# ReSharper fluent indentation

Tags: formatting, resharper

When I format this piece with ReSharper:

```
this.Tabs.Add(bb => bb
             .Horizontal(h => h
                  .Vertical(v => v
                      .Box("0", upperView, "")
                      .Box("1", mainView, ""))));
```

I get:

```
this.Tabs.Add(bb => bb
                     .Horizontal(h => h
                                           .Vertical(v => v
                                                             .Box("0", upperView, "")
                                                             .Box("1", mainView, ""))));
```

But I want it to stay the same. How would I do this?

Comment: Dont you see the extreme indentation?

Comment: Seems that it's IE7's fault that I'm forced to use at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe deselecting

- ReSharper →
- Options →
- Languages →
- C# →
- Formatting Style →
- Other →
- Align Multiline Constructs →
- Expression

reduces the effect.

(Assumed you are using C#.)