# Resharper fluent interface code formatting (align to the dot)

Tags: c#, resharper, code-formatting, resharper-6.0

I read a lot of answers about formatting options for fluent indendation.
( [Resharper formatting code into a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823719/resharper-formatting-code-into-a-single-line) and [ReSharper fluent indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519446/resharper-fluent-indendation) and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-88220 ) like this:

```
mockCrypto.Expect(c => c.Hash("authenticationHashSalt", "ignoring arguments"))
   .IgnoreArguments()
   .Return("hashed");
```

But I have not found information about formatting code like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ICameraController>()
      .To<NikonCameraController>()
      .NamedLikeFactoryMethod((ICameraFactory f) => f.GetNikonCamera());

mock.Setup(framework => framework.DownloadExists("2.0.0.0"))
    .Returns(true)
    .AtMostOnce(); // (it's from moq QuickStart)
```

But the style is very common and I often see it in the documentation for frameworks. 
How to set up Resharper auto-formatting for the use of this style?

Comment: I guess this is not possible now. But we are working on it, I hope that this would be done sometime in 7.1-8.0.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It's good. Resharper is a magical tool, and without this option, but it would be useful.

Comment: I personally avoid this style, because renaming the variable causes subsequent lines to become misaligned again. Instead, I put the first `.` on a new line, and indent each line one tab stop as usual.

Comment: There is a Code Alignment plugin that works well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20427618/492

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using next settings in R# in Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style:

*Line Breaks and Wrapping* -> *Arrangement of Member Access Expressions* section -> *Wrap chained method calls* == *Chop always*

*Tabs, Indents, Alignment* -> *Align Multiple Constructs* section -> *Chained method calls* checked

Result:

[image]

Based on https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/11/12/code-formatting-improvements-in-resharper-71/ . Path for *Chained method calls* was is some version between 7.1 and R# 2018

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Resharper doesn't seem to be able to do this at the moment and it's [an issue that's been flagged for quite some time.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-88220)

As a potentially acceptable trade off, to minimize the pain of Resharper undoing the formatting of existing fluent invocations, you can select "Keep existing line breaks" in Resharper options under "Formatting Style" -> "Line Breaks and Wrapping" -> "Preserve Existing Formatting".

Comment: Is there a similar option for spaces? If I want to make my variable declaration appear as `var thing - - - - - = "hello"` for alignment, how can I stop Resharper undoing it?